# Hilbert space valued random variables as a Hilbert space tensor product

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ a probability space with $L^2$-space $L^2(\Omega)$. I am looking at the space of square integrable $\mathcal{H}$-valed random variables defined as

$$L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{H})=\{X:\Omega \to \mathcal{H} \text{ measurable} : \mathbb{E}[\|X\|^2]<\infty\}$$
which is again a Hilbert space. Now, I was wondering if this space can be identified with the Hilbert space tensor product $L^2(\Omega)\otimes \mathcal{H}$ in some way?

I know Hilbert space tensor products are related to the space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators from $L^2(\Omega)\to \mathcal{H}$, which seems useful here, but I'm not familiar enough with these operators to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $H$ is separable, the two spaces are naturally isomorphic. The isomorphism $L^2(\Omega) \otimes H \to L^2(\Omega, H)$ sends $f \otimes h$ to the function $\Omega \ni \omega \mapsto f(\omega)h \in H$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a few follow-up questions. Why is separability neccesary? The map is clearly always an isometry, so I suppose it's needed for surjectivity?
And also, usually I would think a Hilbert space (or just a vector space) isomorphism was required to be linear, which this map is not, but I guess it's bilinear in a certain sense?

Comment: @Snildt Separability is a bit of a technical issue. It is more about how you define measurability for a function $X: \Omega \to H$, which is far more delicate without separability. For example, depending on how you define measurability, it could happen that $X, Y: \Omega \to H$ are both measurable with $E\|X\|^2, E\|Y\|^2 < \infty$ but $\langle X, Y \rangle$ is not measurable. The “correct” definition of measurability is known as strong measurability in that context, which would actually make the map above an isomorphism as well.

Comment: @Snildt The map I wrote down *is* linear. This is the universal property of tensor product of linear spaces: if you have a bilinear map from $X \times Y \to Z$, then it corresponds uniquely to a linear map $X \otimes Y \to Z$. The fact that the map in the answer preserves the inner product ensures that the map can be extended from the algebraic (just vector space) tensor product to the Hilbert space tensor product, which is the completion of the algebraic tensor product under the norm induced by the natural inner product.

Comment: @Snildt The map from $L^2(\Omega) \times H \to L^2(\Omega, H)$ sending $(f, h)$ to the function $\omega \mapsto f(\omega)h$ is indeed bilinear, which is precisely why the map defined on the tensor product is *linear*. (Recall that in the tensor product, $f \otimes (ch) = (cf) \otimes h = c(f \otimes h)$ for any scalar $c$.)

Comment: Oh, I see. Much appreciated!

Comment: I have been thinking about this strong measurability, and I'm not sure I see why it's needed for measurability of $\langle X,Y\rangle$. If $X,Y$ are measurable, then $X-Y$ is measurable since addition is continuous, and the norm $\|\cdot\|$ is continuous as well, so by the polarization identity, wouldn't the inner product be measurable too?

Comment: @Snildt I should have clarified, I was not referring to the usual notion of measurability when I said the inner product may not end up being measurable. Then again, your argument doesn't work either, because without separability there's actually no reason why $X - Y$ has to be measurable. Of course subtraction is continuous, but that requires you to show $\omega \mapsto (X(\omega), Y(\omega)) \in H \times H$ is measurable. In case of separable spaces this is fine, every open set in $H \times H$ is a *countable* union of basic open sets, but this would not work without separability.

Comment: @Snildt Though I really don't have an example where this fails. I suspect you can find measurable $X, Y$ under the usual notion of measurable where $\langle X, Y \rangle$ is not measurable, but it's just extremely hard to come up with any example of the usual notion of measurability without effectively reducing it to the separable case or some other trivial situations.

Comment: @Snildt The issue with the usual notion of measurability is exactly that - it's very hard to know what is measurable then. To clarify, by this usual notion I meant $f$ is measurable if $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable for all Borel $B \subset H$, or equivalently for all open $B \subset H$. In case of separability, it is enough to check $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable for all open balls $B$, but that is not true without separability, since an open set may not be a *countable* union of open balls.

Comment: @Snildt One specific example - consider the sequence space $H = \ell^2([0, 1])$. Then the function $f: [0, 1] \to H$ defined by $f(t) = e_t$ satisfies $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable for all open balls $B$ but not for all open sets $B$.

Comment: @Snildt Generally speaking, there are four notions of measurability: strong measurability, meaning $f$ is measurable iff it is the pointwise limit of a sequence of simple functions; weak measurability, meaning $f$ is measurable iff $\langle h, f(\omega)\rangle$ is measurable for all fixed $h \in H$; the usual measurability, meaning $f$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable for all Borel $B \subset H$; and the one I just mentioned, $f$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable for all open balls $B$.

Comment: @Snildt They are all equivalent when $H$ is separable, but the equivalence breaks down in the non-separable case. And when I said the inner product may not be measurable, I meant under the weak measurability or the final notion of measurability I wrote down. As an example, let $A \subset [0, 1]$ be a non-measurable set. Let $H = \ell^2([0, 1]) \oplus \ell^2([0, 1])$. Then $X: [0, 1] \to H$ is defined by $X(t) = (e_t, 0)$, $Y: [0, 1] \to H$ is defined by $Y(t) = (e_t, 0)$ when $t \in A$ and $Y(t) = (0, e_t)$ otherwise.

Comment: @Snildt Then both $X$ and $Y$ are weakly measurable and also satisfy $X^{-1}(B), Y^{-1}(B)$ are measurable for any open ball $B$. But $\langle X, Y \rangle$ is the indicator function of $A$, which is not measurable.

Comment: @Snildt It is known that strong measurability is equivalent to weak measurability plus the range being in a separable subspace, and is also equivalent to the usual measurability plus the range being in a separable subspace. It is enough to ensure the inner product is measurable and that the space you wrote down is indeed a Hilbert space. And under strong measurability the map I wrote down in the answer is also an isomorphism.