# functions that are orthogonal to their input

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H=L^2(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^3)$ be a Hilbert space and $V=\{u \in H \mid \langle x, u(x) \rangle = 0 \text{ for a.e. } x\in \mathbb{R}^3\}$ a subspace.

Is $V$ closed? What is the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto $V$?

I think V consists of "rotations"? At least that's how it would work in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case.

Now consider: $\varphi : H \rightarrow \{\text{I don't know}\}, f \mapsto \langle f(\cdot), \cdot \rangle$

If this is a continuous well defined function then $V$ is the preimage of $0$ and hence closed. However I have no idea how to show this. And how can one approach finding the projections?

Regarding the codomain of $\varphi$, the inner product is continous,so also integrable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is closed. Indeed, assume $u_n \in V$ and $u_n \to u \in H$. Then there exists a subsequence $u_{n_m} \to u$ a.e. But then, for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$,

$$\langle x, u(x) \rangle = \lim_m \langle x, u_{n_m}(x) \rangle = 0$$

That is, $u \in V$.

---

The projection $P$ onto $V$ is given by the following map: For $u \in H$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$,

$$[P(u)](x) = u(x) - \frac{\langle x, u(x)\rangle x}{\langle x, x \rangle}$$

Indeed, since $u(x) \mapsto u(x) - \frac{\langle x, u(x)\rangle x}{\langle x, x \rangle}$ is simply the orthogonal projection of $u(x)$ onto $\mathrm{span}\{x\}^\perp$, we see that $\|[P(u)](x)\| \leq \|u(x)\|$, so,

$$\|P(u)\|^2 = \int \|[P(u)](x)\|^2 \, dx \leq \int \|u(x)\|^2 \, dx = \|u\|^2$$

Thus, $P$ is well-defined and in fact a contraction. It is easy to verify that $P(u) \in V$ for all $u \in H$ and also $P(u) = u$ for all $u \in V$. Hence, $P$ must be the orthogonal projection onto $V$.

Note that this also gives an alternative proof that $V$ is closed.

**Remark:** Observe that nowhere in the proof is any property specific to $\mathbb{R}^3$ used. Thus, the proof will actually work for any (separable) inner product space equipped with a (Borel) measure.

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity though, the separable is for it to have a (Hilbert) basis? And why must the measure be Borel?

Comment: @strugglingStudent Not really. I didn't use the existence of an orthonormal basis anywhere in the proof. And if the inner product space is complete (i.e., it is a Hilbert space), then it will have an orthonormal basis regardless of separability. (Of course, an orthonormal basis doesn't have to exist if it's just an inner product space without assuming separability.)

Comment: @strugglingStudent Both separability and Borel are technical conditions to ensure the $[P(u)](x)$ I defined is measurable. I guess you don't actually need Borel, just that the $\sigma$-algebra the measure is defined on contains Borel sets. But since in practice you're going to have either the Borel $\sigma$-algebra or a completion of it, so I just wrote Borel.

Comment: @strugglingStudent As for separability, in nonseparable settings there are several inequivalent notions of measurability, and you need the correct notion (strong measurability) to even make $H$ well-defined. You can check some of the comments I wrote under this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4870366/465145. But even if $u(x)$ is strongly measurable, $[P(u)](x)$ is probably not, unless your measure is just supported on a separable subspace.

Comment: Aha, I see. Thanks alot!